# Unable to select drop down menu

Tags: java, selenium

[image]I want to automate drop down menu using Selenium web driver using Java, but the HTML page has `<option disabledselected>----</option>` (Ref to attached screenshot)

I want to select 2nd menu item from drop down. I've tried many things but every time I'm get an error message.

1st Approach - using `ByVisibleText`:

```
public void selectHomeCommunity(String name){
    Select hmecomm= new Select(hmecommdropdown);
    hmecomm.selectByVisibleText(name);
}

public <Webelement> SelfRegistrationPage Community(String pass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    enterPassKey(pass);
    System.out.println("Entered into Community method");
    pressGoBtn();
}
```

2nd Approach - `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('hmecommdropdown').options.item(0).click().;");
```

3rd Approach - `getFirstSelectedOption`:

```
String selectedLabel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("CommunityDropdown"))).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Every time I'm getting same error as:

> waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP
>   (9a6751455dba60b65479430ff8f9aa00)] -> id: CommunityDropdown]

Comment: Share the relevant HTML please.

Comment: Where is screenshot..?

Comment: Kindly share the html DOM / site URL.

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: Your problem may be because your page is not completely loaded. Using [`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElement())`](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-wait-examples) to ensure that the element you need to work with is visible.

Comment: @ Tuyen, getting error message as : Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (ec815e667b40a36bef1f2e5b6405fdad)] -> id: CommunityDropdown] (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdowns are from a language such as angular then using Select may not work. My suggestion is us seleniums click operations.

1. Click the dropdown to open it
2. Use driver.findElements to find all the webelements for the options inside the dropdown
3. Iterate through the elements and pull out the text in the elements. When you find the text you are expecting perform the click

Something like the following may be useful:

```
public void clickDropdownOption(WebDriver driver, String option) throws Exception{
    waitForDropdownMenuToBeVisible(driver);
    WebElement dropdownMenu = driver.findElement(dropdownMenuLocator);
    List<WebElement> optionElements = dropdownMenu.findElements(dropdownOptionLocator);
    for(int i=0; i < optionElements.size(); i++){
        if(optionElements.get(i).getText().equals(option)){
            click(driver, optionElements.get(i));
            waitForDropdownMenuToBeinvisible(driver);
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Dropdown option " + option + " was not found");
}
```

Obviously if it is a normal HTML dropdown then use the conventional approach

Comment: Hi Raymond, I'm unable to click the drop down to open it, please ref to the attached screenshot for DOM structure.

Comment: @user2447231 Can you check if somewhere else in the DOM has the same ID?

Comment: No, Raymond, No other element with same ID, checked with size(), and it returned 1.